# Sublime Text 3 API: Find text in specific Region

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm currently working on my first Sublimetext 3 Plugin. The idea is, that it scans a certain line for a pattern. I Already found the view.find() function but as far as I can say it scans the whole document.

The final aim is to convert a line with several patterns to a new line with contents from the previous line.

My input would be something like

```
Hello.MyNameIs("Paul", male)
```

and the output shall be something like:

```
MyNameIs = Paul
```

My idea is to use the find function to find the text within the quotes.

```
result = self.view.find(<pattern>, line.begin())
```

The question currently is: what kind of pattern do I need to store the name Paul in result?

Comment: OK, so what is your question? Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. You need to explain exactly what you've done, and where exactly you need help. Also, do you really want `MyNameIs = Paul`, or `MyNameIs = "Paul"` (with quotes)? Please provide several different examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

[find(pattern, fromPosition, flags)](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View)

You can find your text starting from a position, so you have to first determine the position at the beginning of the line.

You can use lines() or split_by_newlines() to divide the view into lines, and begin() will give you the start position of each line.